# Symfony primary key error on form submission: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0'

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, nullable

The below route in the controller works with my `Film` entity for creating the first object in the table - however, the primary key doesn't seem to be incrementing if I try to create a second entry:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Films (film_title, year, set_id, rating) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["The Matrix", null, null, null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

The route from my controller is:

```
/**
 * @Route("/newfilm", name="new_film")
 */
public function newFilmAction(Request $request)
{
    $film = new Films();

    $form = $this->CreateFormBuilder($film)
        ->add('film_title','text',array('label'=>'Film Title'))
        ->add('Save','submit',array('label'=>'Add Film'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($film);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('success_filmadded');
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:new.film.form.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

The relevant code from my Films entity is:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Films
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Films", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_Films_sets1_idx", columns={"set_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Films
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="filmid", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $filmid;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="film_title", type="text", length=65535, nullable=false)
     */
    private $film_title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="year", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $year;


    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Sets
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Sets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="set_id", referencedColumnName="setid")
     * })
     */
    private $set;


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="rating", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $rating;
}
```

I want to be able to add new objects that have NULL for these other parameters still.

Comment: The error is suggests that your id column is not auto--increment (assuming you are using mysql).  Run "describe films" to confirm.  Also run app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql to confirm everything is in sync.

Comment: try to run this command `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` to ensure everything is updated

Comment: Hi both - I ran the `...update --dump-sql` command first which ran without error (but doesn't fit the problem). I then tried the `...update --force` command but get an error: `An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE Directors CHANGE directorid directorid BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL': SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './filmsdb/#sql-4a4_33 to './filmsdb/Directors (errno:150)`

Comment: Add this annotation against your primary key  @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
Then update the database and try again!
It should work!

Comment: Thank you - I have updated my code with `* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")` as you suggested. However I've emptied the database table and tried running both of the `...update...` statements but nothing has changed unfortunately. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Consider just dropping the database creating a new one.  I think you have a sync problem somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad - I've already tried emptying and dropping the database and recreating it from the source SQL code - however after running `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` I'm still getting the same `ALTER TABLE` error as in my earlier comment. Is this the wrong update command to be running?

Comment: I suppose you could run doctrine:database:drop, database:create, schema:create.  But it's all very strange.

Comment: Excellent - thanks very much @Cerad....that fixed it. Could it have been because I generated entities from the database schema that already existed?